# Calculating rate of spread of tree species

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

I'm fairly new to GIS and using ArcGIS for a palaeoecology project at university. I have created a map with isolines (all in the same layer using the contour tool) which represent time of arrival of a tree species.

**I need to work out the rate of spread in km per year** but have no idea how to do this! 
I presume I have to find out the average distance travelled and divide by the time taken but I'm not sure how to measure the distance, as it has spread in more than one direction.  Does anyone have any ideas? I've spent the last two weeks trying different tools and getting nowhere!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a few different approaches here and even have some fun to find things like the spacio-temporal change of the rate of spread (because I imagine that the rate of spread is not uniform in all directions at all times so mapping physical barriers/facilitators depending on the seed dispersal method of your given tree species and climate change against the rate of spread could be fascinating). Anyway, a couple of ideas which spring to mind could include deriving the slope of your 'surface' (easy if you have Spatial Analyst - you would need to recast your contours as time intervals rather than date and then interpolate a raster from it).  The second approach, if you wanted to find out the rate of spread from point A to point B could be to derive a raster surface that represents time taken and to perform a simple Cost-Path analysis on it. If you don't have Spatial Analyst extension and your Institute won't pay for it, then you can try QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you had a raster showing the *exact* date of arrival of the species in each cell.  Its slope raster would estimate the ratios of small changes in date (dt) to small changes in distance (dx), whereas you seek the rate of change of distance with respect to date.  But that is defined to be the limiting value of dx/dt as dt grows small.  Since

```
dx/dt = 1/(dt/dx) = 1/slope
```

it is appealing to **use the reciprocal of the slope to estimate the rate of tree spread.**

In reality you probably do not have exact dates: you only have first known date, perhaps at regular intervals (such as annually).  This will create a slope grid that is filled with zeros, punctuated by near-infinite values.  What you will need to do, then, is *interpolate* among the *actual observations* that were made in order to create an accurate, continuous, smoothly-varying grid of arrival dates.  (How to do that is a huge topic that cannot be adequately addressed here with the limited information given.)  After you have that interpolation, use Map Algebra to compute the reciprocal of the slope grid (computed as an actual slope, not as an angle!).